# IDAPython: Is it possible to determine whether an instruction operand is a constant rather than a variable?

Tags: idapython

Here is my use case:

I am trying to create a script that finds all instances of a particular instruction (in this case wrmsr) and traces back to find out whether the operands for the instruction are hard-coded literals or variables that are set at runtime. This is meant to help me detect a certain flavor of vulnerable driver.

Does IDAPython have a way to query instruction operands to distinguish between literals and variables? How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`idc.get_operand_type()` is a concise way to do this.

e.g.

```
if idc.get_operand_type(ea, 1) == idaapi.o_reg:
    print("that's a register")
```

The operand types are all here: https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/sdkdoc/group__o__.html

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can look at the type of the operand with something like this (ideally with some more error and type checking):

```
  insn = idaapi.insn_t()
  idaapi.decode_insn(insn, ea)
  if insn.ops[0].type == ida_ua.o_imm:
      print("This is the constant value ", insn.ops[0])
```

The possible values for `op_t.type` are here: [IDA SDK: Operand types](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/sdkdoc/group__o__.html).